# VBA Access ：Window named "Enter Parameter Value" appears before automated report generation. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Sub GenerateAndSaveReport()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSearchField As String
    Dim SearchValue As String
    Dim strReportName As String
    Dim strOutputPath As String
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim frm As Form

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Set db = CurrentDb

    strSearchField = "Deal Name"
    SearchValue = "SH-ANHUI"

    strReportName = "Transaction RPT"
    strOutputPath = "C:\Users\JF26070\OneDrive - KBC Group\xue\Access\"

    ' Escape special characters in the search value
    SearchValue = Replace(SearchValue, "'", "''")

    ' Set the parameter value
'    Dim rpt As Report
'    Set rpt = Reports(strReportName)
'    rpt.Parameters("Deal Name").Value = strSearchValue
'    Set frm = New Form_Deal_New
'    DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acNormal, , , , acDialog
'    frm.lstListBox.RowSource = strSearchValue
    
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE [" & strSearchField & "] = '" & SearchValue & "'")
    Debug.Print rs![Deal Name]

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' DoCmd.OpenQuery "Report_A"
        DoCmd.SetParameter strSearchField, SearchValue ' line has bug
        DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strOutputPath & "Report.pdf"
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Report_A"
        DoCmd.Close acReport, strReportName
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found for the specified criteria."
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub

Set parameter line has bug that I cannot solve. Seek for guidance, thanks.
```

What's wrong with my code? Window named "Enter Parameter Value" appears before open Access report generation. The code has bug is pointed out in note.
strSearchField is the column in Table
SearchValue is the the filtering goal
I'm a greenhand in VBA. Please don't dismiss me the question is simple.

Comment: Maybe the white space in the parameter name is a problem. I usually pass the conditions like this `DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[Deal Name] = 'the name'"`.

Comment: I have never used SetParameter. I also prefer to apply filter to form or report with WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenForm or OpenReport command. Advise to avoid spaces in naming convention. Your code attempts to close a query that is not opened.